# How do I get the path of a document open in Preview using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
tell application "Preview"
    set myfile to path of document 1 of window 1
end tell
```

I have verified that my Preview is scriptable (NSAppleScriptEnabled).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a little research and found this

```
 tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Preview"
        set thefile to value of attribute "AXDocument" of window 1
    end tell
 end tell

-- macos comes with php installed you can decode this file name using php
return do shell script "php -r 'echo urldecode(\"" & thefile & "\");'"
```

which i found on [macscripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=5168)

Comment: unfortunately, this gives `thefile` urlencoded an AppleScript has no native urldecode function.

Comment: I up'd that too soon see my modification to the answer

Comment: @mb21 see comment and revision :)

Comment: The script does work here (4 years after the question was asked, on 10.8), but `urldecode(...)` doesn't seem to do anything, `thefile` is `file://localhost/path/to/file.ext` before and after - where it should be `/path/to/file.ext` so it can be interpreted as a `POSIX path`.

Comment: Instead of schell script getting the path can be done by adding `use framework "Foundation"` and `return (current application's NSURL's URLWithString:thefile)'s relativePath as text`

Answer (score 2):

On my 10.6 system Preview doesn't have an Applescript dictionary. This is something that scriptable applications need. While Preview SAYS it can do Applescript, it really can't.

It has no way to translate the "path of document 1 of window 1" into anything meaningful.

Usually people use GUI Scripting to interact with Preview, or they find another way.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is:

```
tell application "Preview" to return path of front document
```

Or, to fit your example:

```
tell application "Preview" to set myfile to path of front document
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the path to the current document accurately even if Preview is in full screen mode, use:

```
tell application "Preview" to return path of document of front window
```